# How to read a specific value from a byte array?

Tags: python, arrays

I have a byte array as b'570 (RFC822.SIZE 11377)'. How can I read the data to fetch the value 11377?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just decode and slice:

```
b'570 (RFC822.SIZE 11377)'.decode('utf-8')[-6:-1]
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. I understood that 'utf-8' encoding converted my byte array to string. But can you explain the portion [-6:-1] as I do not understand the numbering.

Comment: @RishikMani: This is not a tutorial site, so the explanation that you request would be out of place here. Do a web search on "Python string index" and "Python slice".

Comment: Thank you once again. I understood.

Answer (score 1):

```
re.findall(b'\d+',b'570 (RFC822.SIZE 11377)')[-1]
```

is one way you could do it i guess

Comment: I did not know about the regular expression thing at all. Thanks for a new info.

Comment: That will throw an error: `TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object`. You have to decode it first.

Comment: fixed @Sebastian